# Bypass "il2cpp external wbarrier tracker"

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida, bypass

Does anyone know what `il2cpp_gc_set_external_wbarrier_tracker` is and how to bypass it? Every time I hook my function, the application crashes (I'm sure it's because of this anticheat func, not because I'm not using MinHook incorrectly). I have no idea how to bypass it, as all it seems to be is a loop with some unclear checks. Can anyone give advice or at least speculate on what this is? This is how it looks in the decompiler and asm(see screenshots). (My application is `x86`)

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfmLJ.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYS7o.png)
[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD0cK.png)`.`

I couldn't even properly debug this function because it is called almost every millisecond and apparently it is responsible not only for the function I am hooking.

Comment: It's **extremely** unlikely that function is an anti-cheat protection. It's part of the `libil2cpp` used by `IL2CPP`, a script backend of Unity. A lot has been written about IL2CPP [[1](https://blog.unity.com/engine-platform/il2cpp-internals-a-tour-of-generated-code)] [[2](https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2020/06/24/il2cpp-part-1/)][[3](https://www.jacksondunstan.com/articles/4994)] reverse engineering. If you want to illegally crack a game or unethically have an unfair advantage over kids who are just trying to have fun, you must at least be competent enough to properly ...

Comment: ... document yourself and be willing to spend weeks/months doing experiments and tests. That's the unwritten rule in the "warez" world.